# Trouble with Disabling Functions when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, function, button, disable

So I'm working on a school coding project and I'm having trouble disabling a function when a particular button is pressed. I assumed a return command would be the best way to go but my code doesn't seem to be doing the job. Here's an example of the code I tried:

```
    var x = false;

    onEvent("button","click",function(){
       `` x = true;
        newScreen();
      });
      if(x == true){
        return false;
      }else{
        return true;
      }
    }
```

This is taken from the end of a function. Does the if statement have to be directly connected to the function (placed right at the top)? If so, how would I go about coding the function where if it's true, run the code but if it's false, don't (if that makes sense)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = false;

onEvent("button","click",function(e){
   if(x === true) {
      e.target.disabled = true;
      e.preventDefault(); 
      e.stopPropagation(); 
      return; 
   }
   x = true;
   newScreen();
});
```